# Robots.txt and language exclusion

Tags: 6

I want to add a language on my drupal 6 site but I want that Google doesn't index every page in this language (fr).

Can I use robots.txt and and add something like this?

```
Disallow: /fr/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal by default comes with robots.txt file. You can find the file in Drupal Root.

Yes, you can go ahead and change. Below code also should work.

```
Disallow: /fr/
```

But, if you use

```
Disallow: /fr/*
```

As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Universal_.22.2A.22_match)

> Universal * match The Robot Exclusion Standard does not mention
>   anything about the * character in the Disallow: statement. Some
>   crawlers like Googlebot and Slurp recognize strings containing *,
>   while MSNbot and Teoma interpret it in different ways.

Comment: [Robots.txt](http://drupal.org/project/robotstxt) module might come in handy.

Comment: Robots.txt module can be used only if "Use this module when you are running multiple Drupal sites from a single code base (multisite) and you need a different robots.txt file for each one." Otherwise it's easy to edit robots.txt

Comment: I would prefer always editing through admin dashboard. its much easier. provided you play around with robots.txt often